# Align unrelated arrays

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I align arrays like the ones below so that they start at the same distance from the left edge of the paper?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \[\begin{array}{l}
          a + b = c \\
          a + c = b \\
          a + b = c
      \end{array}\]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem \[ a + b + c + d + e + f = g \]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \[\begin{array}{l}
          a = x \\
          a + b = y \\
          a + b + c = z
      \end{array}\]
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can left justify equations using the `flalign` and `flalign*` environments from the [amsmath package](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/amslatex/english/amsldoc.pdf). To indent the equations, just include an appropriate amount of space in the first line of each environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\myindent}{\hspace*{2cm}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \begin{flalign*}
          \myindent & a + b = c & \\
          & a + c = b & \\
          & a + b = c &
      \end{flalign*}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem
     \begin{flalign*}
     \myindent & a + b + c + d + e + f = g &
     \end{flalign*}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \begin{flalign*}
          \myindent & a = x & \\
           & a + b = y & \\
           & a + b + c = z &
      \end{flalign*}
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

There is a temptation to define a new environment that automatically inserts a `\myindent` inside an `flalign`, but doing this sort of thing with an `amsmath` environment usually ends in tears (see section 6 of the [amsmath technical note](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf) for details).

Answer (score 1):

While Ian Thompson answer the question asked about aligning the equations on the left, the usual way of aligning equations is on the equal sign.  Below I show two different way of doing this (with `array` as originally set up, and with the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package):

1. Using a `\hphantom{}` to add the appropriate amount of horizontal space.
2. Using a `\makebox{<size>}{<text>}` to set the given text in the appropriate amount of space.

### Notes:

- [The `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) provides the `\widthof` macro to compute the length used by the `\FitInBox` to typeset the left hand side of the equation with a `r`ight alignment within the approriate amount of space.

All yields similar results:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}% provides the align environment
\usepackage{calc}% for the \widthof macro


\begin{document}
Using \verb|array| along with \verb|\hphantom{}|:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \[\begin{array}{r@{}l}
          \hphantom{{}+c+d+e+f} a + c &{}= b \\
          a + c &{}= b \\
          a + b &{}= c
      \end{array}\]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem 
    \[ a + b + c + d + e + f = g \]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \[\begin{array}{r@{}l}
          a &{}= x \\
          \hphantom{{}+c+d+e+f} a + b &{}= y \\
          a + b + c &{}= z
      \end{array}\]
  \end{itemize}

\hrule\medskip

Using \verb|align| from the \verb|amsmath| package with \verb|\hphantom{}|:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \begin{align*}
          \hphantom{{}+c+d+e+f} a + b &= c \\
                                a + c &= b \\
                                a + b &= c
      \end{align*}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem 
    \[ a + b + c + d + e + f = g \]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \begin{align*}
                                    a &= x \\
          \hphantom{{}+c+d+e+f} a + b &= y \\
                            a + b + c &= z
      \end{align*}
  \end{itemize}

\newpage

\newcommand*{\WidestLeftHandSide}{$a + b + c + d + e + f$}
\newcommand*{\FitInBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestLeftHandSide}][r]{$#1$}}%

Using \verb|align| from the \verb|amsmath| package with \verb|\makebox{}|:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \begin{align*}
          \FitInBox{a + b} &= c \\
                     a + c &= b \\
                     a + b &= c
      \end{align*}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem 
    \[ a + b + c + d + e + f = g \]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit l
      \begin{align*}
          \FitInBox{a} &= x \\
                 a + b &= y \\
             a + b + c &= z
      \end{align*}
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```